# Issues Resizing Image to fit on a printed page

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printing, printdocument

I am trying to print an image (from file) to a the printer using a `PrintDocument`.

I am re-sizing my image so that it is scaled to be full page on the printout when I print this the image is cropped slightly.

**EDIT 2**

I *am* using the margins to calculate the area to use:

```
With printSettings.DefaultPageSettings
    Dim areaWidth As Single = .Bounds.Width - .Margins.Left - .Margins.Right
    Dim areaHeight As Single = .Bounds.Height - .Margins.Top - .Margins.Bottom
End With
```

The bounds of the page are 1169x827 (A4) and with the margins it is 1137x795.

After resize my image size is 1092x682 and I am using the following code to draw it:
    `e.Graphics.DrawImage(printBitmap, .Margins.Left, .Margins.Top)`

The annoying thing is that when I print to the PrintPreviewDialog it is scaled perfectly but when I print the exact same code to the actual printer it does not fit.

**EDIT 3**

Full code can be found at [this url](http://pastebin.com/HxsbEYg0)
Usage:

```
Dim clsPrint As New clsPrinting
    With clsPrint
        .Landscape = True
        .SetMinimumMargins()
        If .ShowPrintDialog Then
            .Documentname = "Some doc name"
            .Preview = False 'When True shows ok
            .PrintImage("filename of a png file")
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: Could you post the code doing the resizing?  It could be you're actually cropping the image, not resizing it.

Comment: According to the [`Bounds` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.bounds.aspx), I see it says, "Use the Bounds property along with the Margins property to calculate the printing area for the page." Should you perhaps be subtracting the values from `printSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins`?

Comment: The likely problem is in the image resizing code.  Just don't resize it, draw it with the Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle) overload.  You'll get much better output quality as a bonus.

Comment: @Hans - Thanks but I don't think this is to blame. I tried using `.DrawImage` and this had exactly the same results. Fine in Print Preview but not when actually printed. I Think this could be a bug in the printer driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution to this problem. I worked around it by using the printer margins when performing a print preview and ignoring the margins (start at 0,0 origin) when actually printing. I believe that this is possibly a bug in the printer driver? But I can't confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Try using e.graphics.VisibleClipBounds for the printable page size in the PrintPage function. As Hans said, it's better not to resize your image before printing.

Comment: `e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds` contains the same width and height as the `PrintableArea` but the origin is 0,0 instead of the `Margin.Left`, `Margin.Top`

Answer (score 1):

You must work with `MarginBounds`:

in `C#`:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(your_image, e.MarginBounds);
```

in `C++/CLI`:

```
e->Graphics->DrawImage(your_image, e->MarginBounds);
```

Note: If your image doesn't have the same aspect ratio you'll need to adjust.  In this example width of the image exceeded the page width:

```
Dim adjustment As Double = img.Width / e.MarginBounds.Width
e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), New Point(img.Width / adjustment, img.Height / adjustment)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are wanting to print a page with a [full bleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_%28printing%29) which most personal printers are not capable of.  As one of the comments above mentions, factor in the margins to re-size the image to the appropriate size.

Comment: Actually I want to print it within the margins - please see EDIT2 to my original post